# Remove settings from Gutenberg core block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

From the `core/image` block in Gutenberg, I am trying to remove both the 'image size' and 'image dimension' settings. Is this possible to do without copying the entire block and removing the parts I wish to omit?  The only things that come close to what I want is A) removing an image style:

```
// Remove 'rounded' default style.
wp.domReady( () => {
  unregisterBlockStyle('core/image', 'rounded');
});
```

and B) removing a panel from the editor (not a block) with:

```
const { removeEditorPanel } = wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post');
removeEditorPanel( 'discussion-panel' );
```

I could use CSS to hide the settings, but I wish to remove them entirely.

Comment: You can use https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit . You will however still need some code from the block

Comment: @niklas, would you apply this to the `core/image` block into this as the second argument of `wp.hooks.addFilter()`?

Comment: Like in the example but only include the parts of `InspectorControls` that you want to use. Find that in the `core/image`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to remove the Image Size settings but you can test this approach I used to remove the Dimension settings for Margin and Padding.

```
import { select } from '@wordpress/data';
import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks';

/**
 * Component to disable dimension settings based on block context.
 *
 * @param {Object} settings - The block settings object.
 * @param {string} settingsName - The name of the settings being modified.
 * @param {string} clientId - The block id.
 * @param {string} blockName - The block name.
 * @returns {Object} The updated block settings object.
 */
const disableDimensionSettings = (settings, settingsName, clientId, blockName) => {

    // Retrieve current user with capability to update settings
    const { canUser } = select('core');
    const currentUser = canUser('update', 'settings');

    // Retrieve the current post type
    const { getCurrentPostType } = select('core/editor');
    const currentPostType = getCurrentPostType();
    
    // Disable these block settings.
        const disabledBlockSettings = [
            'spacing.padding',
            'spacing.margin',
        ];

    if (
        disabledBlockSettings.includes( settingsName ) &&
        currentPostType === 'page' &&
        !currentUser // Add this condition for Admin only access
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return settings;
};

addFilter(
    'blockEditor.useSetting.before',
    'my-plugin/disable-dimension-settings',
    disableDimensionSettings
);
```

Here is the link for the full guide on how to [Restrict WordPress Gutenberg Block Settings Based on Post Type, User Roles, or Block Context](https://jeffreycarandang.com/restrict-wordpress-gutenberg-block-settings-based-on-post-type-user-roles-or-block-context/)